# show georss feed on gmap

Tags: php, georss

I am new to georss. i have my georss feed but i don't know how to check it on gmap.

Is there any way to check geoRss feed on google map.
(I work on php platform)

Answer (score 0):

This post on the google maps api blog should pont you in the right direction - http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/kml-and-georss-support-added-to-google.html